# Array Key with Space in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I have used `{{$property.[Rent or Sale]}}` or `{{$property[Rent or Sale]}}` for getting a value for the key Rent or Sale.

It is showing `syntax error unexpected')' expected ']'`.

Comment: So you mean to say it is giving an error message when you have key name separated with space? @SaibalChakravarty

Comment: Yes @PassionInfinite

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me: `config('menus.main_menu.Main\ Section') }}`

So probably if you try to escape the space with \ it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, According to **best practices of PHP**, we should **never use** space in 
array keys.

Secondly, This is fixed by me and my friend @curos. The issue was with the improper regular expression which was interpreting `'or'` as `default keyword`. The following is the method having regex problem.

```
     public function compileEchoDefaults($value)
     {
       return preg_replace('/^(?=\$)(.+?)(?:\s+or\s+)(.+?)$/s', 'isset($1) ? $1 : $2', $value);
     }
```

Which is updated as following:

```
     public function compileEchoDefaults($value)
     {
        return preg_replace('/^(?=\$)([^\'"]+?)(?:\s+or\s+)(.+?)$/s', 'isset($1) ? $1 : $2', $value);
     }
```

The above method is in **vendor/laravel/framework/src/compilers/BladeCompiler.php**

This updated regular expression will not interpret `'or'` as `keyword`.

**please see : This bug has been fixed by laravel**

Answer (score 0):

your syntax was wrong you have to write it like
{{$property.Rent}}
{{$property.Sale}}

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this.

`<td>
 <? echo $user->{'Rent or Sale'}; ?> 
</td>`